# How to uninstall software which was direct installed from web browser or was not installed by msi cmd

Tags: python

I want to write a python script to uninstall software that wasn't installed by MSI but unable to find the cmd command. I've searched but found nothing.

I am working on uninstalling software from windows. I know I can uninstall software that was installed by using MSI installer by the command `msiexec.exe /x "msi_file_path" /log "uninstall_log_file_path"` and it's working using MSI but I'm facing difficulty in uninstalling software that was not installed by MSI file.

Also, I tried to uninstall by cmd using the command: `wmic product where name="Google Chrome" call uninstall` but it gives an error that `No Instance(s) Available.` although I can see in it is installed from App and features.

Comment: If you want python, then why also the tags `PowerShell` and `cmd` ?

Comment: I can call cmd command through python and it'll work.

Comment: You can call cmd by using cmd too, but as already implied, you're spamming tags. Either you want help with, a powershell.exe issue, and use the [[tag:powershell]] tag; a cmd.exe issue, and use the [[tag:cmd]] tag; or a python.exe issue, and use the [[tag:python]] tag. Using all of those tags implies that you're looking somebody to do it for you, after making no effort, not even an effort to decide how you wish to go about the task. You are still at the research stage, not at the asking for help with a programming issue stage. Please do some research, before updating your off topic question.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever be it the source of installation it can be uninstalled from settings. Just go to Settings > Apps > Type the name and search it , then select it and click on uninstall. [See this for help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OPgt.png)

Hope this helps you out. :)

If this is anything python related, please explain your problem, a bit more.

Comment: I want to write a python script to uninstall software which wasn't installed by MSI but unable to find the cmd command. I've searched but found nothing

Comment: @Sheraram_Prajapat: Put that in your question.